# Why are the results of my 4-bit Ripple Carry Adder weird?

Tags: verilog

I was trying to implement a 4-bit Ripple Carry Adder. Everything works fine, but the outputs are extremely confusing. Here is my Verilog code:

```
module sum(A,B,Cin,S);
    input A,B,Cin;
    output S;
    wire t;

    xor X1(t,A,B);
    xor X2(S,t,Cin);
endmodule

module carry(A,B,Cin,Cout);
    input  A,B,Cin;
    output Cout;
    wire t1,t2,t3;

    and A1(t1,A,B);
    and A2(t2,B,Cin);
    and A3(t3,A,Cin);

    or O(Cout,t1,t2,t3);
endmodule

module fulladder(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
    input A,B,Cin;
    output S,Cout;

    sum S1(A,B,Cin,S);
    carry C1(A,B,Cin,Cout);
endmodule

module fourbitadd(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
    input [3:0] A,B;
    input Cin;
    output Cout;
    output [3:0] S;

    wire [2:0] t;

    fulladder FA1(A[0],B[0],Cin,S[0],t[0]);
    fulladder FA2(A[1],B[1],t[0],S[1],t[1]);
    fulladder FA3(A[2],B[2],t[1],S[2],t[2]);
    fulladder FA4(A[3],B[3],t[2],S[3],Cout);
endmodule
```

And the testbench:

```
module fourbitadd_tb;
    reg [3:0] a,b;
    reg cin;
    wire [3:0] s;
    wire cout;

    fourbitadd DUT(a,b,cin,s,cout);
    initial 
        begin
            $monitor(a,b,s,cout);
            cin=1'b0;
            a=4'b0000;b=4'b1111;
            #5 a=4'b0001;b=4'b1111;
            #5 a=4'b0101;b=4'b1101;
            #5 a=4'b1101;b=4'b1001;
            #5 a=4'b1111;b=4'b1110;
        end
endmodule
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to get outputs other than 0s and 1s.
Here is the output I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in the code as such and in your output. Perhaps you could make your `$monitor()` output more readable by using the following

```
$monitor("a = %04b, b = %04b, sum = %04b, cout = %01b",a,b,s,cout);
```

The `%b` format specifier ensures the output is displayed in the binary format. `$monitor()` displays the number in the decimal format by default. Running your code with the above statement gives the following output.

```
a = 0000, b = 1111, sum = 1111, cout = 0
a = 0001, b = 1111, sum = 0000, cout = 1
a = 0101, b = 1101, sum = 0010, cout = 1
a = 1101, b = 1001, sum = 0110, cout = 1
a = 1111, b = 1110, sum = 1101, cout = 1
```